# Returning the first non-zero result from Pool.async_map

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous

I am using the python multiprocessing library in order to run a number of tests on a large array of numbers.

I have the follow syntax:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(processes = 6)
res = pool.async_map(testFunction, arrayOfNumbers)
```

However I want to return the first number that passes the test, and then exit. I am not interested in storing the array of results.

Currently `testFunction` will return 0 for any numbers that fail, so if doing this without any optimisation, I would wait for it to finish and use:

```py
return filter(lambda x: x != 0, res)[0]
```

assuming there is a result. However since it is running asynchronously, I want to get the  non-zero  value as soon as possible.

What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but it is a working approach. Adding tasks to a queue is non blocking and the program will keep operating. Now by storing all the possible return values I can iterate over them by myself.

The return values are actually close to a promise object, now by checking their `ready()` function I can check if the result is ready to be read. Then using the `get()` method I can verify what that value is. If I know the value is 0, I can terminate the pool early and return the final result.

A minimal working example demonstrating this is the following:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


def worker(value):
    print('working')
    time.sleep(3)
    return value


def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)  # Only two workers
    results = []
    for n in range(0, 8):
        value = 0 if n == 0 else 1
        results.append(pool.apply_async(worker, (value,)))

    running = True
    while running:
        for result in results:
            if result.ready() and result.get() == 0:
                print(f"There was a zero returned")
                pool.terminate()
                running = False

        if all(result.ready() for result in results):
            running = False

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The expected output would be:

```
working
working
working
There was a zero returned

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I created a small pool of 2 processes, that are calling a function that will sleep for 3 seconds and then return either 1 or 0. Currently the first task will return a 0, and the program will early terminate after the results are available.

If there is no terminating task, the line:

```
if all(result.ready() for result in results):
    running = False
```

Will terminate the loop if all processes are done.

If you would like to now all the results, you can use:

```
print([result.get() for result in results if result.ready()])
```